# Is anti-Brahminism a symptom of Kali Yuga?

Tags: kali-yuga

[Anti-Brahminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Brahminism) is the ideology of being opposed to Brahminism and Brahmins.

Is anti-Brahminism a symptom of Kali Yuga?

Do any scriptures say this?

Comment: Most of the Brahmins of modern days are not following teachings of Vedas. This could be one of the reason of losing the authority.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I agree with you, but people should look at those Brahmins who truly follow the teachings of the Vedas.

Comment: They are bare minimum. If we really want to overcome anti-brahminism, then those bare minimum have to take the initiative to spread the knowledge of Vedas to all Hindus regardless which Varna they belong to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is anti-Brahminism a symptom of Kali Yuga?

**Yes, losing faith in Brahmins and going against them is a symptom of Kali Yuga according to the scriptures.**

From the *[Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp156.htm#page_621)*:

> PARÁŚARA.--Hear, Maitreya, an account of the nature of the Kali age,
>   respecting which you have inquired, and which is now close at
>   hand.....
>
> Men of all degrees will conceit themselves to be equal with
>   Brahmans....
>
> In the Kali age, Maitreya, men, corrupted by unbelievers, will refrain
>   from adoring Vishńu, the lord of sacrifice, the creator and lord of
>   all; and will say, **"Of what authority are the Vedas? what are gods
>   or Brahmans?**

Comment: Saying that Brahmins are not special is not the same as being anti-brahmin. It's an equalization. I think there are other sources which actually say so (about anti-brahmins I mean), but this source does not prove the point.

Comment: @user1952500 Well, asking "of what authority are Brahmins or Vedas," basically means you are going against their authority and opposed to their ideology (Vedas), which is how anti-Brahminism partly works in modern day India.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the term, thanks for the clarification @Ikshvaku.

Answer (score -2):

I am a Brahmin myself and I am writing this **harsh truth** that I have myself seen and experienced. It is **lengthy** so please bear with me while I write **my** **experiences and my visuals**.

It is true that **most of the Brahmins are not following the teachings of Vedas.** Not only this, I believe **they are also distorting the facts and teachings of Vedas and Upanishads for their own benefits.**

Also, according to **Kalki Purana**, a verse says that ***Brahmins, instead of indulging themselves in the holy activities, such as learning Vedas, doing puja to Gods, they will spend their time in satisfying their bellies and genitals.*** Even though **Brahmins are not supposed to eat Non-Veg food and drink alcohol**, increasingly we are seeing that they **do these two harmful things so as to have fun.**

Not only these things we are seeing but also, Brahmins **have divided themselves!** 
I **could not find a single Hindu Scriptures which talks about these divisions.** The **divisions** are

1. Smarthas
2. Mudras
3. Iyengar

and many more...

These are the **so-called "sub-castes" of Brahmins**, which they have **done for their own selfishness.** I do not believe in this division. **A Brahmin boy from one sub-caste cannot marry Brahmin girl of another sub-caste.** **If done so, parents won't speak to the children.** I'm saying this because I've seen live examples of some of my own parents' friends who've done this to their children. I'm **not saying this everyone is like this but most of them are, especially the old people.**

Coming over to doing **Puja of God**. The reason why **Brahmins are priests** **because** **they know the religious scriptures**. But increasingly, **they are becoming lazy and giving the post to Shudras.** According to the **non-distorted Shastras**, the **Shudras' main task is to serve the people** by doing work such as cleaning, washing and so on. They **don't know how to recite the Veda Mantras**. When **reciting the Mantras**, the **pronunciation of the syllables must be perfect so that it reaches to God and also, it impresses God and creates a positive energy**. But, this won't happen if Shudra is the priest. 
**Even, a lot of Brahmins lazily recite wrong mantras that create a negative environment in the temples that we visit.** 
I personally had an experience when I went to **my hometown's Shiva temple**. Here, **instead of feeling rejuvenated, I felt bored, lazy and also, I was unable to chant any Shiva mantra out of devotion as the level of devotion was very less for me**. Later, I saw that the **priests are chanting the Vedic Mantras in the wrong fashion**, leading to this **negativity**.

I've also seen **Brahmins forcing their children to get married**. They say that ***if you get married, you will have a great status in the society.*** But, our **Shastras never say that marriages are compulsory.** **If marriages are compulsory**, then, **Why is Lord Hanuman Bachelor despite himself being a Brahmin?**

There are many other reasons such as **hypocrisy, wearing the sacred thread and a ponytail for showing off to people** and other reasons to prove that **most Brahmins are morons in the age of Kali Yuga.**

Please feel free to comment if you find anything wrong or distorting. I have shared this based on my personal experiences.

Comment: Welcome! Personal opinions are not considered as valid source on Site. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Hi. When I was writing this answer, the guidelines told me that don't write answers based on opinions but back it up by experiences or references. It's present below the editor where we write our answers. That's why I wrote in this manner. But I have backed up with my own experience in this answer. Please do see at the beginning and also at the end of the answer where I've written that the main answer is based on my experience and not on my opinion. I've also referenced Kalki Purana.

Comment: This is not Quora where we can write opinions. All your answer contains only personal experience, comments and opinions what happened with you. [Personal experiences are not considered a valid source](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/266/5212). Take a [tour].

Comment: @KVAjay Personal experience is [not considered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/811/277) as source here. You should cite some authoritative/reliable sources, preferably scriptures.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll modify my answer soon.